# Want to Fetch date from sql to textbox textmode=date

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datatable

I tried to fetch a date from textbox where textbox mode is date.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate"    required="required" TextMode="Date" runat="server"  class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>


txtDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Date"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

but still it showing dd-mm-yyyyy in frontend

want to fetch value to textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a browser / HTML 5 specification issue, not webforms. It only takes a RFC3339 formatted date (YYYY-MM-DD).

So use

```
txtDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```